# How to catch XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange function result?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to catch the returned value of `eAC_callback` if it was `false` or `true` when `eAC` calls it during `onreadystatechange`. Can I do that? How?

```
function eAC(emailData) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {
        return false;
    }

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("email", emailData);

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = eAC_callback;
    httpRequest.open('POST', "http://example.com/p_PEC.php");
    httpRequest.send(fd);
}
```

eAC_callback returns `true` or `false` when `readyState is 4` and `status is 200`

```
function eAC_callback() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
            if(response.error === 0){
                return true;
            } else {
                if(response.error === 1){
                    return false;
                }
                if(response.error === 2){
                    return false;
                }
            }       
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: make your ajax call sync to do that but sync ajax will frezee your browser except firefox

Comment: you don't use the return keyword in a callback except as a void early exit, returning a value makes no sense at all because it cannot "go anywhere"... the fix is actually simple though, just do whatever you want to do after calling the ajax inside the callback instead of outside it.

Comment: @dandavis thats the actual code right now. doing the stuff inside the callback. but I was wondering if I could get the result from the function with the ajax so I could do this `if(!eAC(emailData))`. Seeing the comments I guess I can't. too bad.

Comment: it's not too bad, you just put the code in your if statement into the callback. if use a reusable ajax function, it's not a lot of ugly boilerplate like you have now, it's just wrapping a single anon function around the code in question. thanks to closure, that wrapped code can fit into an existing app in the exact same place as your theoretical if statement with no refactoring or interface freeze. it's the 21st century way to code simple and efficient async operations.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to catch the returned value of `eAC_callback`

Then you will have to wrap it in another function:

```
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (eAC_callback()) {
        …
    } else {
        …
    }
};
```

However, you will never be able to `return` any results computed in the asynchronous callback to the `eAC` function that installed the callback (long ago). See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572) - supply a callback or return a promise.